# Font baseline in Silverlight v3

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

How do I get the baseline of a font in Silverlight v3.  I need to be able to do some simple font metrics so that I can reproduce some online render using an external markup system and make the output looks the same.

Silverlight renders fonts from top,left but the external system uses font baseline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not possible.  Microsoft removed the Baseline property from the FontFamily class and there is no font metrics class.  Not sure if this was necessary to support non-Windows UIs; would seem to be a large oversight otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189010(v=vs.95).aspx

**TextBlock.LineHeight**
LineHeight sets the height of every line of content in the overall TextBlock.LineHeight is truly the baseline to baseline height

I think you can build ad hoc solution by creating a dummy TextBlock to extract LineHeight data for your baseline calculation on the go as you read external markup...